# Get HTML Text of Rich Text editor in javascript section of Oracle Apex

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I am trying to display html text of rich text editor of oracle apex in javascript/jquery  using alert..

I tried like ..

```
alert($('#P8_TEXT').val());
```

or

```
alert($x('P8_TEXT').value);
```

not working...it shows null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `alert($v('P8_TEXT'));`

Answer (score 0):

try with `text()`  `val()` is for input tag

```
alert($('#P8_TEXT').text());
```